# Chromedriver is not executable on Teamcity with linux-agent problem

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, teamcity

So I have a regression suite using Java/Selenium etc which runs fine headless on my local PC.
Now I am trying to create a build configuration on our TeamCity server and within the code I have this little snippet -

```
if(IsOnTeamCity()) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "_drivers/chromedriver");
}
else {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\_drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
}
```

and

```
private static boolean IsOnTeamCity()
{
    String environmentVariableValue = System.getenv("TEAMCITY_VERSION");
    if (environmentVariableValue != null && !environmentVariableValue.isEmpty())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

When I start a run all works well until we get to the tests.
[image]

[image]

Then I get this error

```
    [When logged in as a staff member I can see the the navigation cards] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /opt/buildagent/work/815e6cc9c618cd9d/_drivers/chromedriver
```

So am I setting webdriver.chrome.driver up wrong? Or is there other settings I need to look at please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chmod 755 cured this problem for me